# Google Form Script Submit After Response Populate Form with previous entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a Google Form for new students to sign up for our classes. The Form is set up to Submit After Response, starting the form over with all of the fields cleared and reset. I would like to add a script on submit that, if the user selects Submit After Response, that the Form would populate a majority of the same fields, while clearing and resetting some of the others. This is because when a parent signs their children up for their classes, I don't want them to have to enter all their contact info each time they add a new child.

The form in question can be found here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1NXBrs7zydaWsOvVlQMC8OXRykzT2fryXhiCASl21FG0/viewform

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this time it is not possible to manipulate an active Google form with Google script during user submission. About the only thing you can do with GAS regarding forms, is create and alter the makeup of a form during its initial development.

It's a bit confusing, but I've searched everywhere for exactly what you are trying to do. What I ended up doing was creating a Google web app and then deploying it for public use. A lot more manual work but a lot more customizable.

Maybe alternatively what you can do is, since all you want to do is make the submitting for the parents a lot easier, add several similar fields for something like 'Child 1', 'Child 2', 'Child 3', etc. and before each page for the new child, have the form ask the parent of there is another child, and depending on their answer you can have them progress to the next section of form. Now with this style, you could have multiple students per row of data in your presiding spreadsheet, so you'd either have to manually alter the spreadsheet at a later time, or create a spreadsheet script that automatically manipulates the data for you as needed. This is probably your best bet.

Comment: Just saw your reply Gerneio, I will look into that. Thanks.